# Cannot declare class because the name is already in use in (same file)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm getting the following error while running my web app:

```
[Fri Jan 15 19:25:23 2021] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class App\Http\Livewire\Customer because the name is already in use in /home/<username>/Projects/<project_name>/app/Http/Livewire/Customer.php on line 9
```

The declaration error is basically complaining about its own file and I'm not sure why.
This is the content of the Customer.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use App\Models\Customer;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Customer extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    
    public function render()
    {
        $customers = Customer::where('user_id', Auth::id())->paginate(9);
        return view('livewire.customer')->with(['customers' => $customers]);
    }
}
```

Can someone help me untackle this problem?

Comment: Did you try with `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: you can't alias a class to `Customer` and name your class `Customer` in this file ... which `Customer` are the references to `Customer` supposed to be a reference to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To resolve the conflict just use

```
use App\Models\Customer as AppCustomer;
```

Then your class can use `AppCustomer` instead of `Customer`.

```
$customers = AppCustomer::where('user_id', Auth::id())->paginate(9);
```

Comment: I did guess the issue was probably related to the clash of the names, but I didn't know aliases existed! Thank you so much!